# How to return dynamic values from a function

Tags: function, go, return, polymorphism, return-value

How to implement a function like this? `<What_to_use_here>` ?

```golang
func callfunc(type string) <What_to_use_here> {
    if type == "string"{
        return "I am a string"
     } else if type == "integer"{
       return 1
     }
    return nil
}

type Sample struct {
   value_int int
   value_str string
}

type Sample s
s.value_int = callFunc("integer")
s.value_str = callFunc("string")
```

I need to assign the value coming from the callFunc to a specified type as shown. So I think returning interface will not work. Need help.

Comment: Use an interface type (preferably as narrow as possible) that all possible return types satisfy. It would be nice to know more about the real use case...

Comment: [The language is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
type Sample struct {
    value_int int
    value_str string
}

func callFunc(typ string) interface{} {
    if typ == "string" {
        return "I am a string"
    } else if typ == "integer" {
        return 1
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var s Sample
    s.value_int = callFunc("integer").(int)
    s.value_str = callFunc("string").(string)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/QEPVMvAhkMQ

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `interface` to return dynamic values from go lang function,here is simple program for the same:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := callfunc("string")
    fmt.Println(data)
    data2 := callfunc("integer")
    fmt.Println(data2)
}

func callfunc(str string) interface{} {
    if str == "string" {
        return "I am a string"
    } else if str == "integer" {
        return 1
    }
    return nil
}
```

Output:

```
I am a string
1
```